# Extract Audio data (to pass API ) from live streaming m3u8 without saving output into file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I want to extract Audio data from live url and pass this to API without saving  output to a file on disk. What is the command to write output into memory stream?

The Command I used in c# is as below:

-i \"http://wowza.xyz.com/live/definst/livesimstream/playlist.m3u8\" -c copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 4 \ -segment_list test.m3u8 -segment_format mpegts stream%%05d.ts

When I use this command in c# it gives me error Access Denied.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i http://wowza.xyz.com/live/definst/livesimstream/playlist.m3u8 -vn -acodec copy -f mpegts | [wherever you want it piped to]`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment. Can you give me an example of how to pipe Audio? I execute this command 
-i http://wowza.xyz.com/live/test_/livesimstream/test.m3u8 -vn -acodec copy -f mpegts pipe
It throws below error :  
Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
      Metadata:
        variant_bitrate : 1437737
      Stream #0:2: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
      Metadata:
        variant_bitrate : 1437737
  pipe: Permission denied

Comment: Hi, this command returns output -i http://wowza.xyz.com/live/test_/livesimstream/test.m3u8 -vn -acodec copy -ac 2 -ar 48000 -f s16le pipe:1  can you help me to get this output in segments? as it keep on extracting audio. It would be better if we can have this segments so that it extract lets say first 10 seconds and give output and then next 10 seconds and so on.. As this is from live streaming.